Compare 5 columns with another sheet
I am trying to compare Sheet 1 row E to I and see if at any of these values matches the corresponding column C to G in sheet 2. Both sheets have the same header. If any of cells matches in sheet 2 on the same row , then I want to copy cell H from sheet 2 to cell J in sheet 1 and then copy the row in sheet1 it to another sheet - sheet3. I am not sure how to do it either using formula or VBA. Any help will be appreciated.
=IF(SUMPRODUCT(Sheet1!E2=Sheet2!C:C),--(Sheet1!F2=Sheet2!D:D)--(Sheet1!G2=Sheet2!E:E)--(Sheet1!H2=Sheet2!F:F)--(Sheet1!I2=Sheet2!G:G)"MATCH","")

No formula can do this because you're looking up values from columns ...F, ... and then replacing the value in column F.

I have edited the question. I messed up the formula. Apologies.

Pls. try this in Sheet1!J2 and drag down =IF((E2=Sheet2!C2)+(F2=Sheet2!D2)+(G2=Sheet2!E2)+(H2=Sheet2!F2)+(I2=Sheet2!G2)>0,"match","") with cell copy =IF((E2=Sheet2!C2)+(F2=Sheet2!D2)+(G2=Sheet2!E2)+(H2=Sheet2!F2)+(I2=Sheet2!G2)>0,Sheet2!H2,"")

@Black cat
Thank you for your reply. What I meant by this line (f any of cells matches in sheet 2 on the same row) was that Sheet2 has many rows and the matching values does not necessarily have to be in row 2 in Sheet2. It has to lookup the whole of sheet2. The formula does not work if I  change the match to whole column in sheet2 instead of just specific cells.

Then give a try to this formula =IF(SUM(--(Sheet1!E2=Sheet2!C2:C22)+SUM(--(Sheet1!F2=Sheet2!D2:D22))+SUM(--(Sheet1!G2=Sheet2!E2:E22))+SUM(--(Sheet1!H2=Sheet2!F2:F22))+SUM(--(Sheet1!I2=Sheet2!G2:G22))),"MATCH",""). Use only the exact ranges on Sheet2, otherwise there can be runtime problems and out of resource errors.

SIDENOTE: This above formula is an array formula. If not use in 365 then CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER is needed.

Sorry just realized that there are a lot of blank cells and it is matching the blank cells as well. Is there a way to only match against cells with values and how do i edit the formula to return values in column H instead of the word match? I get #Spill when I amend the formula to reference the column instead of Match. Also is there a formula to match at least 2 columns in the row instead of just 1?
